# Meaning of this Italian Phrase - Stay Baell

Tags: word-meaning

I have heard this phrase in Italian blogs, Instagram accounts etc.., I know a little bit of Italian and couldn't co-relate this to anything. 
My hunch is that it means stay beautiful (or well). Does the baell come from Neapolitan or some other dialect? In what circumstance is this phrase used?

Comment: Could you point to some example usages of the phrase? It's hard to recognize a sentence from the mixed recollections of a non-speaker.

Comment: I have heard sometimes “stay in bell” as a jokingly literal translation of “stai in campana”, which is slang for “stai attento/a”, meaning “be careful / watch out”. I don't know the reason for this slang expression, though.

Comment: Here you go http://baellsquaddoingthings.tumblr.com/ , https://twitter.com/search?q=%23baell

Comment: http://www.blitzquotidiano.it/foto-notizie/giosada-vince-x-factor-foto-ma-che-vuol-dire-baell-2339679/

Comment: @egreg you should probably make an answer of that and include the link and a summary of the content

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be a new entry in the language of youths. According to http://www.blitzquotidiano.it/foto-notizie/giosada-vince-x-factor-foto-ma-che-vuol-dire-baell-2339679/ this word has been invented by an Italian singer/actor named [Giosada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giosada) as a variant of “bell” (Bari dialect for *bello*).

The word spread rapidly in the social networks (never heard before, to be honest). So *stay baell* could mean *be nice* or variants thereof.

Comment: Grazie, I think this answers my question

Comment: +1 but this is horrifying. I know that languages evolves and that we should aim to describe rather than prescribe, but.. ugh...

Comment: @DenisNardin I can't agree more. `;-)`

Comment: I wonder whether ichthyologists, even amateur ones, exchange horrified remarks about scorpion fish or other non-cute fish on their forums.

Comment: @DenisNardin, don't worry it will disappear in the fogs of internet as soon the next meme and trendy characters will appear on the scene... who knows if we are just victims of some expedient to stand out in a tv contest

Comment: @DaG, ichthyologists have no control over the subject of their study, and don't use fish to communicate

Comment: Undoubtedly so, @WalterTross, but they eat fish and chips and own fish bowls. Nevertheless, when discussing species of fish, they leave those at home. In other words, I am not sure that this is the best place to express personal tastes about stuff, be it words or fish.

Comment: @DaG From the scientists I know they are more likely to exchange pictures of them with captions commenting how cute they are. Nevertheless I'm sorry if this reaction is inappropriate, but I *really* don't want a language learner to get the impression that this expression is in any way close to standard Italian...